# How to upload the images on Uploadthing using express and reactjs

Tags: reactjs, express, upload, mern, image-upload

I tired the to upload the images on Uploadthing I can't.
I provide these how to fix this problem

my server folder
index.js file
[index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtJTr.png)

uploadthing.js
[uploadthing.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oe2kW.png)

my frontend folder
app.jsx where I imported the uploadButton
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Lo9W.png)

utils/upload.js were I defined the uploadButton
[upload.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyEpu.png)

can you tell me were is the issue and output is that on tab and it loading every time
[output on tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaJmW.png)

I want to anyone this question and give good solution to fix that

Comment: Post the code as plain text with code format, not screenshots

Comment: if click on underline blue text then it will show the screenshots @LinDu